# Python program using logging enters sleep mode for 3 hours

Tags: python, logging, stdout

I use python logging module and suddenly the process enters sleep mode for 3 hours. What are the possible reasons?  The codes related to logging are as followings.

a1.py

```
logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)
logger.info("foo")
```

a2.py

```
logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)
logger.info("bar")
```

main.py

```
logging.basicConfig(filename=str(final_log_file), format=head)

logger = logging.getLogger()

logger.setLevel(logging.INFO)

console = logging.StreamHandler() # <--- comment it and error goes away

logging.getLogger('').addHandler(console)  # <--- comment it and error goes away
```

Comment: what do you mean sleep mode? Hangs? Is the CPU busy?

Comment: It shows `Sl+` in `top`.
The cpu is not busy.
I use `strace -p pid` and it shows the process is blocked by writing into file.

Comment: The code you gave should terminate instantly. Please give all related code!

Comment: `StreamHandler` will output to stderr. Presumably stderr is blocked.

Comment: @HåkenLid Could you explain a bit more? I think this is the reason.

Comment: I commented `StreamHandler` and the error went away. So what's happened?